# Registering a Prometheus metric in Python ONLY if it doesn't already exist

Tags: python, prometheus

I'm making use of the multiprocess prometheus collector (in python), but likely this problem would exist for single process as well.

Is there a way to check if a Counter Metric already exists, to prevent the attempt of registering a duplicate ?  Multiple calls to the below code generate the appended error. Or alternatively to check if a given metric exists, and get it.

Some kind of look up in the Registry ? The docs seems rather lacking.

Code:

```
logging_counter = prometheus_client.Counter('test', 'test')
```

Error generated:

> ValueError: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'test',
> 'test_total', 'test_created'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with how MultiProcessCollector was setup ... make sure that at the subprocess level you initialize with CollectorRegistry and not Registry.

Proper Solution:

```
prometheus_client.multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(prometheus_client.registry.REGISTRY)
```

Incorrect Solution:

```
prometheus_client.multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(CollectorRegistry())
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very hacky way to do this but this is how I made it work for a single process;

> self.registry = CollectorRegistry()

```
def collect_metrics(self):
    sorted_keys = sorted(self.stat_msg_dict.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        ..... getting metric_key, metric_name, current_value .....
        gauge = self.registry._names_to_collectors.get(metric_key, None)
        if gauge is None:
            gauge = Gauge(metric_key, metric_name, registry=self.registry)
        gauge.set(current_value)
```

In this particular instance all my collectors are gauges.